Python API to get spl token details given token solscan address
Is there python api to get spl token details like current price, total supply, mint address with given token address along with solscan address?

Yes that is helpful, I got another way to fetch price using python's aiohttp library to fetch current price from dex screener.
import aiohttp

async def get_dex_screener_price(token_address: str) -> float:
    try:
        url = f"https://api.dexscreener.com/latest/dex/tokens/{token_address}"
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as response:
                data = await response.json()
                if data.get('pairs') and len(data['pairs']) > 0:
                    return float(data['pairs'][0].get('priceUsd', 0))
                return 0.0
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting price for {token_address}: {e}")
        return 0.0


Yes its quite easy. The solscan address is irrelevant.
Sign up for a free account at https://www.helius.dev/ and get an api key
Your script should send a request to the RPC URL given to you
import requests
response = requests.post(
"https://mainnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=",
headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"},
json={"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"test","method":"getAsset","params":{"id":"RCHj61JJj8UPZmczfVDneVLRGzVkBzVqV3U7JEvpump"}}
)
data = response.json()
Replace the API-KEY with yours from the helius dashboard, and replace RCHj61JJj8UPZmczfVDneVLRGzVkBzVqV3U7JEvpump with whatever token
reponse will look like {
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": {
"interface": "FungibleToken",
"id": "RCHj61JJj8UPZmczfVDneVLRGzVkBzVqV3U7JEvpump",
"content": {
"$schema": "https://schema.metaplex.com/nft1.0.json",
"json_uri": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXH7RaicX6ayFPUAm1DpqFxQcpkYP3zMwCPmkLi8WvfuL",
"files": [
{
"uri": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmX1Adh91kWV2apbp26uUWPtEyepDRaQUe1X9ay13ASqLE",
"cdn_uri": "https://cdn.helius-rpc.com/cdn-cgi/image//https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmX1Adh91kWV2apbp26uUWPtEyepDRaQUe1X9ay13ASqLE",
"mime": "image/png"
}
],
"metadata": {
"description": "OZZY is not just а small cute cat, he is Viral & Memable cat",
"name": "OZZY",
"symbol": "OZZY",
"token_standard": "Fungible"
},
"links": {
"image": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmX1Adh91kWV2apbp26uUWPtEyepDRaQUe1X9ay13ASqLE"
}
},
"authorities": [
{
"address": "TSLvdd1pWpHVjahSpsvCXUbgwsL3JAcvokwaKt1eokM",
"scopes": [
"full"
]
}
],
"compression": {
"eligible": false,
"compressed": false,
"data_hash": "",
"creator_hash": "",
"asset_hash": "",
"tree": "",
"seq": 0,
"leaf_id": 0
},
"grouping": [],
"royalty": {
"royalty_model": "creators",
"target": null,
"percent": 0,
"basis_points": 0,
"primary_sale_happened": false,
"locked": false
},
"creators": [],
"ownership": {
"frozen": false,
"delegated": false,
"delegate": null,
"ownership_model": "token",
"owner": ""
},
"supply": null,
"mutable": false,
"burnt": false,
"token_info": {
"symbol": "OZZY",
"supply": 999924332063329,
"decimals": 6,
"token_program": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
"price_info": {
"price_per_token": 0.000363679,
"currency": "USDC"
}
}
},
"id": 1
}
